# Reading multiple strings in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have to read strings from the user based on a number `n` and store `n` strings in `n` different variables. I'm stuck with how to put them into different strings. Please help me out.

This is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      int b;
      String s="";

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter verifying number: ");
      b = in.nextInt();

      for (int i=0; i<=b; i++) {

          System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
          s = in.nextLine();
      }
```

So if `b = 5,` i have to input 5 strings from the user and store them in 5 different string variables. I'm able to take it from the user but not able to assign them into different variables. Can u please help me out?
Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend reading about Java data-structures. Maybe you could make use of the ArrayList

Comment: Read up on arrays...

Comment: Use an array or a `List<String>`.

Comment: @JoshEngelsma use `List<String>` and initialize it as `ArrayList<String>` rather than directly using `ArrayList`.

Comment: Are you allowed to use an array, or an ArrayList?

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza I agree, either way, the question is so open ended :)... you could use an array, you could use a List, you could use 5 separate string values...

Comment: @JoshEngelsma my point is about using interfaces rather than direct class implementation when possible.

Comment: yes arraylist and array are allowed. thanks.. i will have a look at them again and will proceed with them. thanks guys.

Comment: Use a mutable array `ArrayList` with a `String` generic

Answer (score 6):

If you know exactly the number of input then use an Array, if not use a ArrayList

With Arrays

```
  String []inpupts = new String[b];
  for (int i=0; i< b; i++) {
      System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
      inputs[i] = in.nextLine();
  }
```

With ArrayList

```
  List<String> inpupts = new ArrayList<String>();
  for (int i=0; i< b; i++) {
      System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
      inputs.add(in.nextLine());
  }
```

Comment: I updated your answer a little to correct `<=` problem (there shouldn't be `=`). I also renamed `b` to `size` which seems more descriptive but that is subjective matter so feel free to edit it back to names used in OP code (OK nvm Luiggi took care of it :D).

Comment: Shouldn't it be "in.next()" instead of "in.nextLine();", because nextLine() moves the scanner position to the next line and returns the value as a string, so "Enter a string: " gets printed twice before user can give his input and so only 1 input is taken.

Answer (score 3):

From your code (<= b) I am assuming you just started learning Java. Therefore, I edited your solution and am proposing the following, if this is okay?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      int b;


      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter verifying number: ");
      b = in.nextInt();
      //necessary to do due to Enter key pressed by user
      in.nextLine();
      String s[] = new String[b];
      for (int i=0; i<b; i++) {

          System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
          s[i] = in.nextLine();

          // You can check at the same time if this is what you entered
          System.out.println("I have received this sring:  "+s[i]+"\n");
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an array and store it in an array like below:

```
String s[] = new String[b];//use b+1 if you need b+1 entries
for (int i=0; i<b; i++) {//use <=b is you need b+1 entries
      System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
      s[i] = in.nextLine();
}
```

You can then access your values as:

```
for (int i=0; i<b; i++) //use <=b is you need b+1 entries
      System.out.println("Entered string was : " + s[i]);
}
```

Comment: Why `new String[b+1]` and not `new String[b]`?

Comment: See OP's for loop, he takes values from  user starting at 0 till b. Hence b+1.

Comment: That means OP's for loop is wrong due to `Scanner.nextInt` requiring a call to `Scanner#nextLine` to consume the Enter pressed by user.

Comment: Hmm may be or may be not.. May be OP himself can figure that out which is being not clear here.

Comment: Hope @LuiggiMendoza it makes sense now.

Comment: There is something wrong with `i<=b`. OP wants to store `b` numbers, but your array can contain `b+1` indexed `[0, 1, 2, ..., b]`.

Comment: Shouldn't it be "in.next()" instead of "in.nextLine();", because nextLine() moves the scanner position to the next line and returns the value as a string, so "Enter a string: " gets printed twice before user can give his input and so only 1 input is taken.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution :**

You can use something like this.

You can change your code as :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
      int b;
      String s="";

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("Enter verifying number: ");
      b = in.nextInt();
      in.nextLine(); // To get a new line

      for (int i=0; i<b; i++) {

          System.out.println("Enter a string: ");
          s = in.nextLine();
      }
```